# Dispatch_async not being called and nslog within it is not as well

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to run this code, but it is not working. I've tried other solutions listed with the same problem, but so far none have worked.I tried putting an nslog inside  dispatch_async, but it doesn't even get called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.keyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Keyboard" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addGesturesToKeyboard];
    self.inputView = self.keyboard;
}
- (void)addGesturesToKeyboard {
    [self.keyboard.searchKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSearchKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (void)pressSearchKey {
    NSInteger numberOfResults = 3;
    NSString *searchString = self.keyboard.textField.text;

    NSString *encodedSearchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *finalSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?term=%@&entity=song&limit=%ld",searchString,numberOfResults];

    NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:finalSearchString];
    dispatch_queue_t iTunesQueryQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,  kNilOptions);

    dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
        self.keyboard.firstLabel.text = @"hi";
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:searchURL];

        if (data && !error) {
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            self.results = [NSMutableArray array];
            NSArray *resultsArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
            for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in resultsArray) {
                // self.keyboard.firstLabel.text = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"trackName"];
            }  
        }
    });

    [self.keyboard.view1 setHidden:YES];
    [self.keyboard.view2 setHidden:NO];
}
```

UPDATED

```
dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

        if (data && !error) {
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

            NSArray *array = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.keyboard.firstLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where are you putting this code? If you put an `NSLog` immediately before this code, does that print anything?

Comment: There's not enough information for your question to be answered as is, but it looks like the `dispatch_async` is never reached.

Comment: This code is within a method `- (void)pressSearchKey)` which is called from another method `[self.keyboard.searchKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSearchKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` which is within `- (void)addGesturesToKeyboard` and is called in `viewDidLoad`. When I put an NSLog before the that code, the NSLog works.

Comment: You need to supply more complete code sample (including `NSLog` statements that you are seeing and those you aren't). There is no problem with the above code, so your problem clearly rests elsewhere.

Comment: @Rob There is really nothing else to show. `NSLog(@"Works")` for example does not work inside `dispatch_async(iTunesQueryQueue, ^{
});` but it does work outside of it. I'm doing this in a `KeyboardViewController` which is a subview of `UIInputViewController`

Comment: You have to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e., you have to provide us a code sample that, if we try the code, it will reproduce the problem). Create a test project with the above lines of code (log before `dispatch_async` and again inside it) and it will work fine. So your problem rests elsewhere. If you can't provide us an example where we can reproduce the problem, we simply cannot help you.

Comment: @Rob I updated it with as much code as I could. Please note I am setting the label to "hi" as an nslog as this is a keyboard which doesn't show logs because it's an extension.

Comment: Thanks. FYI, I don't know if there are other issues, but the attempt to update a UI control from the background queue will not work correctly. All UI updates have to be dispatched to main queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding a block to the queue, you need to have the system service the queue.  This is done by by calling `dispatch_main()`, `NSApplicationMain()`, `UIApplicationMain()`, or similar at the end of your initialization in `main()`.

Example:

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        printf("Example\n");
    });

    dispatch_main();
}
```

Furthermore, why are you passing kNilOptions to dispatch_get_global_queue?  Please just pass 0.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know much about dispatching

Comment: There is sample code in the answer.  We can't help you further without you clarifying your question.

Comment: When I add `dispatch_main();` to the bottom, it just freezes

Comment: It doesn't freeze.  It starts servicing the queues.  The main thread is just waiting for something to do (and there is nothing to do, so it just waits).  This is a very contrived "Hello World" example to show how the system works.

Comment: Thanks for providing more context for your code.  Based on that, I suspect your main thread is already servicing the dispatch queues through your usage of NSApplicationMain() being called by your main() elsewhere.  You should add logging to make sure that you really are getting to that point in code.

Comment: I just updated it. I believe this should work, but it crashes.